# Don´t listen to other people’s gossip

Tags: english-to-german

> höre nicht auf den Klatsch von anderen

Habe ich den englischen Satz korrekt übersetzt?

Comment: "korrekt" ist relativ; Viele Varianten sind möglich. Diese wäre eine davon, allerdings nicht optimal. "Klatsch [und Tratsch]" ist kaum gebräuchlich, hat doch nichts mit "klatschen" zu tun oder? Mir fällt selbst kein passendes Nomen ein, "das Lästern", "die Lästerei" ist abstrakt, nicht unbedingt hörbar. "auf etwas hören" meint ohnehin "befolgen, sich danach richten", was hier nur eingeschränkt funktioniert, wenn eigentlich "zuhören" gemeint war, was im Englischen (absichtlich?) zweideutig ist.

Comment: Yes, you did. Nonetheless this question is off-topic since this site doesn't offer translation services. Please take the [tour](https://german.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: man würde kurz sagen "läster nicht" (don't gossip), "glaube nicht an Gerüchte, die erzählt werden", was ohne Kontext ne relativ hohle aussage ist. Schließlich steckt in jeder Sage ein Funken Wahrheit, warum sollte man da nie nicht hinhören?

Comment: Bitte lies [die Antworten zu dieser Frage](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/628/how-do-i-ask-good-on-topic-questions-about-meaning-translations-or-difference).

Comment: @olafant die zehntausendste Frage über Casus-Grammatik im Anfänger-Level ist natürlich viel interessanter, oder es ist einfach zu schwierig die ältere Duplikat-Frage zu suchen. Jedenfalls ist das hiet gar kein translation-req. Allenfalls proof-reading, was aber glaube ich bei kurzen Texten weniger verboten ist als bei seitenweise Fehlerlese. Lezteres wird eindeutig häufiger als Proofreading bezeichnet. Der übliche Kommentar in einem Fall wie hier lautet: "wobei sind sie sich denn unsicher?"

Comment: Ein Vorschlag - `Hören Sie nicht auf den Klatsch und Tratsch von anderen [Menschen].`

Comment: "Lass die Leute reden ..." [summsumm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AaQcnnM2a70) .

Comment: Danke euch allen! Ich werde eine Übersetzung wieder nicht fragen

Comment: Denk daran, das *nicht* an die richtige Stelle zu setzen. Jetzt hast du geschrieben, dass du etwas *wieder nicht* tust. Also z.B. *Er hat die Tür **wieder nicht** zugemacht.*  Das ist etwas anderes als *Er hat die Tür **nicht wieder** zugemacht.*

Comment: Und ja, Übersetzungsfragen wollen wir hier eigentlich nicht beantworten, weil wir dann praktisch nur noch damit zugeschmissen werden würden. Wenn du eine Verständnisfrage daraus machst – also selbst mehr Zeit investierst – sind sie ok. Es ist einfach das Missverhältnis zwischen dem Aufwand des Fragenden und dem der Antwortenden, dem wir nicht anders begegnen können.

Comment: @Janka Habe kurz gestockt bei dem *m* in zugeschmissen. ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Habe ich den englischen Satz korrekt übersetzt?

Yes. Cmp. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klatsch

> "Klatsch [und Tratsch]" ist kaum gebräuchlich

That opinion I cannot support, though.